# Why does iterating through a for loop with a findInbackGround() fail?

Tags: android, iteration, parse-server, yelp

So I have decided to play with the yelp API as a challenge for myself... Clearly I bit more than I can chew... What I am trying to do is iterate through a YelpAPI Response and check if it exists in a column, however it checks only the last value in the Response and it doesn't even match that... Is there an alternative? I think the issue is limited to the fact that it works on a new thread,overwriting the old one each time through the iteration... There might be a completely different way of approaching this.. Below is the code

```
localityVenueLocations = new String[2 * response.body().businesses().size()][4];
ParseGeoPoint venuePoint;
String venueName;
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().businesses().size(); i++) {
    venuePoint = new ParseGeoPoint(response.body().businesses().get(i).location().coordinate().latitude(), response.body().businesses().get(i).location().coordinate().longitude());
    venueName = response.body().businesses().get(i).name();
    venue = new ParseObject("HotSpots");
    //Log.i("AppInfo", venueName);
    ParseQuery < ParseObject > qVenues = ParseQuery.getQuery("HotSpots");
    //int size = qVenues.whereEqualTo("venue", venueName).find().size();
    //Log.i("AppInfo", String.valueOf(size));
    qVenues.whereEqualTo("venue", venueName).findInBackground(new FindCallback < ParseObject > () {@
        Override
        public void done(List < ParseObject > objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objects.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i("AppInfo", "Match for " + venueName);
                    Log.i("AppInfo", "Success checking data");
                    Log.i("AppInfo", String.valueOf(objects.size()));
                } else {
                    Log.i("AppInfo", "No match for " + venueName);
                    Log.i("AppInfo", "Failed at query");
                    Log.i("AppInfo", String.valueOf(objects.size()));
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("AppInfo", "Failed at error");
                e.getCode();
            }
        }
    });
    Log.i("App Info, Business", venueName.toString());
    Log.i("App Info, Lat", venuePoint.toString());
}
```

Comment: `it checks only the last value in the Response and it doesn't even match that` how to you observe that?

Comment: I use the log statements, its worth noting I'm using the log statements to see at which point this occurs. Maybe I'm not checking the right place either.

Comment: one of the first thing to notice is the scope of `venueName`. it is apparently an instance field, and is modified in the loop. The value you log is probably not the same as the value when you called `whereEqualTo`.

Comment: So you're saying that it should be defined outside the loop? Most of the variables are defined outside the loop FYI, Sorry. I'll fix that.

Comment: because that variable is used in the loop and takes all the values iteratively, there is no reason for it to be an instance variable. you should start by making it loop-local (and final): `final String venueName = ...`

Comment: okay so inside the for loop then but outside the functioncall?

Comment: So I added the recommendation you suggested and that worked wonderfully... Now if I can just get the whereEqualto working right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather unrelated solution, the problem was that reading  items from the parsequery meant that every item in that class had to be set to public read/write, which wasn't set before.